Problema con cookie que desaparece al recargar el navegador
Estoy creando un api con express y tengo el siguiente problema: Al iniciar sesión y las credenciales son válidas, creo un Token con JWT y este lo almaceno en una Cookie por 24hs. Una vez realizado eso, me redirige al panel del admin. PERO, ese panel tiene un useEffect para realizar una peticion al back que chequea que exista una cookie y el token sea válidado. El problema, es que la cookie se borra al redirigir la página y no puedo ingresar al admin, porque no hay cookie.
NECESITO AYUDA POR FAVOR!! Ya no se como buscarle una solución.
Gracias!!
const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.SECRET_SIGN_JWT)
          res.cookie('token', token, { 
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ,
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: true
          })


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! La cookie desaparece del navegador?? o no llega al back?? son dos cosas muyyyyyy distitnas...

Seguramente sea un problema de rutas al guardar la cookie, agrega el codigo de como la estas guardando, por favor lee como hacer un [example]

@gbianchi Al iniciar sesión exitosamente, la cookie se crea con el token de JWT, pero al refrescar la web, se borra.. Entonces, al redirigir al admin, desaparece y al back llega vacío..

@JefferzonBol Arriba está el código de como creo la cookie! Eso esta en el controlador de inicio de sesión.. Si es exitoso, entonces pasa eso..

Una duda, esto lo estas probando en localhost o desde un servidor, si es asi, tienes instalado un certificado ssl?

Tambien verifica que tengas instalado el middleware de cookies para poder manipularlas correctamente

y la cookie figura en el navegador? y la cookie esta guardada con la ruta que corresponde? es raro que el navegador borre la cookie...

@JefferzonBol Probando desde localhost, funciona a la perfección! Pero cuando realicé el deploy no anda.. Tengo configurado el middleware perfecto! Antes de las rutas y todo.. Ya no se que hacer!!

@gbianchi Si!! Al iniciar sesión, se crea la cookie con el token perfectamente. Pero al recargar se elimina... NO SE PORQUE :(
